# Bash script pass find files to awk [Mac]

Tags: bash, awk, zcat

I have some gzipped log files in a directory and they look like this:

```
log/day_1_time_log_1.log.gz
...
log/day_1_time_log_100.log.gz
log/day_1_location_log_1.log.gz
...
log/day_1_location_log_100.log.gz
```

I would like to take the 4th column (some `json` strings) from all logs containing the string `time` and cat them into one file. This is what I did and I am getting `zcat: unknown compression format` error.

```
find logs/* -name *time* | zcat | awk -F"\t" '{ print $4 }' > output.json
```

What is wrong with my code? Can I pass that directly into `awk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xargs`:

```
find logs/ -name '*time*.log.gz' -print0 | 
    xargs -0 -I % gzcat % | awk -F'\t' '{print $4}' > output.json
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am getting this error for each file: `zcat: can't stat: logs/day_1_time_log_1.log.gz (logs/day_1_time_log_1.log.gz.Z): No such file or directory`

Comment: I changed `zcat` to `gzcat` and it fixed the problem. Could you update your answer? Thanks!